# How to mock user interaction ("fromUser=true") with the SeekBar in a Robotium test?

Tags: android, robotium

My code distinguishes user and code interactions with the SeekBar using fromUser parameter passed to onProgressChanged() method:

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean fromUser) {

    if (fromUser) {
        // execute only if it was user interaction with the SeekBar
        ...
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to test my SeekBar with robotium I'm not able to "mock user interaction with the SeekBar":

```
solo.setProgressBar(mSeekBar, newValue);
```

onProgressChanged() callback is executed with fromUser == false.

Is it possible to write Robotium test that sets SeekBar's progress and mocks user interaction (fromUser == true) at the same time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve that with method setProgressBar, because it uses [setProgress](https://github.com/RobotiumTech/robotium/blob/master/robotium-solo/src/main/java/com/robotium/solo/Setter.java#L100) from [ProgressBar.setProgress](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/android/widget/ProgressBar.java#545) so there is fromUser set to false by default.

1. solution is to use click on screen - but you actually don't know exactly in which point (% of progress) you hit, if you hit on progress bar at all.
2. solution is to use reflection - use setProgress method with extra parameter (fromUser), so it will use the protected method. I can help in implementation of that in case you have problems with it.
3. solution is to ask robotium team to implement method from 2nd point.

Comment: Thank your very much @maszter! Posted my solution that uses Reflections.

Answer (score 6):

**Solution (Reflections)**

[SeekBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html) is an indirect subclass of the [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) that has a public [setProgress(int)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/widget/ProgressBar.java#ProgressBar.setProgress%28int%29) that has only one line that calls package method [setProgress(int, boolean)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/widget/ProgressBar.java#ProgressBar.setProgress%28int,boolean%29) and passes fromUser == false to it. It is possible to use Reflections and to call [setProgress(int, boolean)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/widget/ProgressBar.java#ProgressBar.setProgress%28int,boolean%29) directly and pass desired fromUser parameter:

```
private void setSeekBarProgress(int newProgress, boolean fromUser) {

    Method privateSetProgressMethod = null;

    try {
        privateSetProgressMethod = ProgressBar.class.getDeclaredMethod("setProgress", Integer.TYPE, Boolean.TYPE);
        privateSetProgressMethod.setAccessible(true);
        privateSetProgressMethod.invoke(mSeekBar, newProgress, fromUser);
    } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fail("Error while invoking private method.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a custom SeedBar which override `onTouchEvent` to change progress by calling `setProgress`, that cause the parameter `fromUser` of `onProgressChanged(...)` always false! I cannot recognize whether the progress is changed by user or code. Your function solve my problem, it's excellent, thanks :)

Comment: Same problem @li2