# Robotium setProgressBar - onStopTrackingTouch is not fired

Tags: android, robotium, seekbar

I have a problem with writing tests in robotium for testing my application flow. On my main screen (Fragment) I have a seekbar that is calculating some data in `onStopTrackingTouch(Seekbar sb)` method. This data is used to open a new fragment with more details. By using a robotium `setProgressBar()` it seems that it sets progress in the right place but this method is not invoked so I can't proceed to the next fragment. Is there any way to simulate a proper user behavior, that will trigger this method?

English is not my mother tongue so please excuse any errors on my part. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a little workaround in my case because Reflection didn't solve my problem ( or probably I don't know how to implement the solution). Just a simple drag on a view :

```
 SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) solo.getView(R.id.distanceBar);
            int[] seekBarLocation = new int[2];
            seekBar.getLocationOnScreen(seekBarLocation);
            final float xStart = seekBarLocation[0];
            final float yStart = seekBarLocation[1]+seekBar.getHeight()/2;
            final float xEnd= xStart+seekBar.getWidth()/2;
            final float yEnd = yStart;
            solo.drag(xStart, xEnd,yStart,yEnd,50);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider use the Reflection and call the setProgress method directly.
Please see the idea details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24289735/how-to-mock-user-interaction-fromuser-true-with-the-seekbar-in-a-robotium-te).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but  could you give me a little hint how should it be done? I mean, I've tried using the code from your link, it sets my seekBar aswell but it still don't fire the onStopTrackingTouch that I've overrited in my fragment.